# Is using clone() -Node class method- good for performance?

Tags: dart

I'm using clone() in a `for` loop.  I wonder if it's a good practice for performance.

```dart
var myTable = new TableElement();
var clonableRow = new TableRowElement();

for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  clonableRow.append(new TableCellElement());
}

for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
  myTable.append(clonableRow.clone(true));
}
```

instead of..

```dart
var myTable = new TableElement();

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var aRow = myTable.append(new TableRowElement());
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    aRow.append(new TableCellElement());
  }
}
```

Which one is the best for performance?  Do you have another solution? (like a native factory constructor for Table that I'm not aware about..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without real data, how about benchmarking it? But it only worth the work if you have a performance problem – don't do premature optimization!

But if you do a benchmark in Dart, you should read [this guide](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/benchmarking/). The internal of the Dart VM make real benchmarking with correct results difficult. Your code won't get optimized until it's hot (has run some times). Running the VM in checked mode makes a difference, too!